# how can I pass the value between controller methods and then to the view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I know it may be a duplicate question, but it really drives me crazy, how someone can help me..

In bills_controller, I have a post action: `apply_repay_list`, in this action I generate a form : `@jd_form` which has the detailed info about the bill, and can be auto submitted,I want to post it to `payment` action

the logic is : 
user is in `myBills.html.erb`, he can see how much money he should pay,
at the bottom of the page, there is a pay bill button, when he clicks
the button,it takes him to `payment.html.erb`, he can then choose the payment methods like paypal or alipay to pay the bill.
The problem is: I can generate the form, but I'm confused about how to
post it to payment action, when I click the pay bill button , I got
`nill class for html.safe`, which means `@jd_form` never pass to the view
what I'm doing worng ? can someone help?
​

```
# bills_controller 

    def apply_repay_list #post action
        ..........
       ......
        trading = Trading.new
        trading.user_id=@user.id
        trading.trading_type=5
        trading.money= total_remain_amount
        trading.relate_ids = bill_ids[1,bill_ids.length-1]
        trading.trading_status=2
        trading.cporderid="order#{@user.id}_#{@user.mobile_number}_#{Time.now.to_i}"
        trading.save
        byebug
        trading = Trading.find(trading.id)
        @jd_form = Jd.gen_form(trading)
        respond_to do |format|

          format.html { redirect_to :action => 'payment' , result: @jd_form}
           format.json { render json: {status:0,status_text:'ok',data:trading.simple_hash}}
        end
    ​
       end

​
​
def payment  #get action

end
​
end
​
#view
#myBills.html.erb
<%= link_to "pay bill", payment_bills_path, class:"pos_fixed btn-css text_center color_gold font-18"%>
​
#payment.html.erb
#this is a hidden button, cause the form will be auto submit, and then redirect to 
#payment provider like paypal's page
<div style="display:none;">
<%= @jd_form.html_safe %>
    </div>
```

routes.rb

```
resources :bills do
    collection do
      get 'list'
      post 'apply_repay'
      post 'apply_repay_ahead'
      post 'apply_repay_list'
      get 'detail'
      get 'myBills'
      get 'myBillsDetail'
      get 'payment'
    end
  end
```

Comment: how is `myBills.html.erb` connected to `apply_repay_list`?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev  I think myBills.html.erb does not connect to apply_repay_list,  I will update the post and put the routes info

Comment: `redirect_to :action => 'payment' , result: @jd_form` - how do you access `result` in the payment action?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev   I used `render json: params`  in payment action, but its not working,  I think i did not do it right.   I also tried the session, something like `trading = Trading.find(trading.id)  @jd_form = Jd.gen_form(trading)  session[:form] = @jd_from`   then in payment action `@form = session[:form]`  I still cant get the value of @jd_form

Answer (score 0):

Add a new post route to handle the payment:

```
resources :bills do
  collection do
    get 'list'
    post 'apply_repay'
    post 'apply_repay_ahead'
    post 'apply_repay_list'
    get 'detail'
    get 'myBills'
    get 'myBillsDetail'
    get 'payment' 
    post 'perform_payment' # <----
  end
end
```

Add the new action to your controller:

```
def perform_payment
  # ....
end
```

Add that route to your form_for:

```
<%= form_for @jd_form, url: perform_payment_bills_path %>
```

If @jd_form has an id that you need to use in the perform_payment action, then you need to add an :id to the route:

```
resources :bills do
  collection do
    get 'list'
    post 'apply_repay'
    post 'apply_repay_ahead'
    post 'apply_repay_list'
    get 'detail'
    get 'myBills'
    get 'myBillsDetail'
    get 'payment' 
  end

  member do
    post 'perform_payment' # <----
  end
end
```

Form:

```
<%= form_for @jd_form, url: perform_payment_bills_path(@jd_form) %>
```

Let me know if that is what you're looking for.

Comment: I dont think it is what I want,   @jd_form is already a form, why do I need form_for?  also I'm dont understand why I need add another post action

Comment: Forms usually do a post request, `payment` is a get request. form_for is just an example, you need to adapt it to your scenario.

Comment: Can you elaborate more about "nill class for html.safe"? Please provide some rails logs showing the request and the error.